# Wordpress header changes from page to page

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, customization

I know this is very general, but I have a wordpress site (theme: Lighthouse by Outstanding Themes) where the site title looks perfect on the frontpage, but is all broken up on several subpages and other top-level pages.

All I've done is edit the site title with custom css with margin-left to make it not centered. The header is the same for all pages and the code should be the same as well. Does anyone know what could be causing the title to be perfect on some pages whereas the lines are all broken up on other pages?

Thanks !

The html is like this:

```
<div class="site-header">
      <div class="site-branding">   
      <a class="home-link" href="https://homepage.com/" title="title" rel="home">
                          <span class="site-title">Title</span>
            <span class="site-description">Site description</span>
                      </a>
      </div><!--.site-branding-->
    </div>
```

- S

Comment: Can you share examples of the code? It would help the community answer. The only thing I can think of the body class is affecting the new css you have edited. Each page/post on wordpress has specific classes on the <body> tag.

Comment: @CraigEvans Here is the css in question, though I doubt that will help you, .site-title {
 font-family: "Segoe UI", Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype", "Dejavu Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif; ;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 255%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 padding-left: 8px; 
 padding-right: 8px;
 margin-left: 40%;
}

Comment: Please do not paste code in comments.  Put it in the body of the original question where it can be formatted nicely.